# Excel - function that returns a matrix from a reference to its centre and radius

Tags: excel, matrix, excel-formula

I am performing some matrix operations with `SUMPRODUCT`. I have a convolution kernel that I will apply to my dataset.
However, I also have a field somewhere that defines the kernel size.

Now, based on my kernel size, I will have several convolution kernels, which I think I can in some way get via `VLOOKUP`. However, that's only my convolution kernel, it's not my data matrix.

Currently, I wrote `SUMPRODUCT(ConvolutionKernel!$A$1:$C$3;Data!H8:J10)` in cell `I9` of my convolution result. I would like to write something similar to :

`SUMPRODUCT(MAKE_MATRIX(ConvolutionKernel!$B$2; 2); MAKE_MATRIX(Data!J8; 2))`

(in reality, my `$B$2` here would be the `VLOOKUP` thingy). `2` is the kernel size - `MAKE_MATRIX(Xn; 1)` should return the `Xn` cell, `MAKE_MATRIX(Xn, 2)` should return `X-1 n-1:X+1 n+1`, etc.

Comment: just checking, you are aware of the matrix functions like MMULTIPLY?  There are others as well.  Thought you would like to know since SUMPRODUCT is not a true matrix operation.

Comment: A excel formula can only produce results in the cells it is applied to.  IE. is I enter =A1+B1 in cell B2, the results will only show in B2 and not the surrounding.  If I apply an array formula to a range, that one array formula will apply the same formula to all cells in the range.  To apply a formula to a dynamic range of cells you would need to use VBA.

Comment: I am aware of MMULT, thankfully I am multiplying square matrices together (as in convolutions), so the result shouldn't matter. If MMULT is better, I'll happily switch to it - but so far, they both produce the same result.

Comment: @ForwardEd I don't want to apply my formula to a dynamic range of cells - I am only interested in applying it to, say, cells in A1:Z26. However, what I want is the formula to be dynamic.

Comment: Do you know the maximum size of matrix that you will be dealing with?

Comment: The Data matrix could be 256x256 or 512x512. The Kernel radius would be less than 4 (that is : the kernel matrix would be a 7x7 matrix at most).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118249/discussion-between-forward-ed-and-fzd).

Answer (score 2):

### The [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) function

This is a volatile function.  It is ok to use as long as you are not dealing with a large number of volatile functions in your workbook or that the volatile function are not dealing with large amounts of data in their calculations.

[OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) is composed of 5 parts:

Offset( A, B, C, D, E)

- A is your reference point for the rest of the offset function.  It does not have to be on the same worksheet as where it is being called.  You just need to put in the right address format for your needs.
- B is how many rows from the reference point you want to move.  0 will keep you on the reference point.  Negative integers will move up that many rows from the reference point.  Positive integers will move down that many rows.
- C is how many columns from the reference point you want to move using the same method as B above.
- D is the number of rows you want to pull or work with.  0 means you wont pull any information. 1 will pull just the row you are working with, 2 will pull 2 rows.
- E is the number of columns you want to pull or work with and works in the same manner as D above.

If offset is entered in a single cell it will display the first element even if you pulled a 3x3 area of information.  You can however use the OFFSET to replace a range/address in another function calculation.

---

### The [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) function

Now if you are building out your matrix on another sheet as we previously talked about and you know the MAXIMUM size your matrix will be, you could use the following NON-volatile function to pull the matrix using the [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) function:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$SS$513,A1,B1)
```

Where A1 is the number of rows to work with counting from the top, and B1 is the number of Columns to work with counting from the left.  Since you want square Matrix to be pulled, A1=B1, so the following could be used:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$SS$513,A1,A1)
```

$B$2:$SS$513 is the maximum size of matrix you would be working with.  A full sheet reference could also be use but then then you **may** run into problem maximum cell calculations.  Its quicker if you can define the maximum range you might be working with.

### Update II

The example below is a generic 15X15 matrix with the coordinate relative to the center, J9, being each of the individual cell values.  You will note I dumped the size of the square matrix to be returned in B2.  I then used the INDEX formulas below to determine the address of the top left and bottom right corner since these would be how you would define your range.

#### Top Left

```
=INDEX(1:1048576,ROW($J$9)-($B$1-1)/2,COLUMN($J$9)-($B$1-1)/2)
```

#### Bottom Right

```
=INDEX(1:1048576,ROW($J$9)+($B$1-1)/2,COLUMN($J$9)+($B$1-1)/2)
```

[image: J9 centre generic matrix]

now 1:1048576 is the whole sheet reference.  This could be reduced to the maximum matrix size for the J9 centre point of $B$1:$R$17.  I used the full sheet reference since you had two difference size matrix to deal with and all you would need to do is define the centre point for either (J9=>New point).  This will work for you if the centre point does not change.

Now INDEX is kind of interesting as it actually returns a cell address and displays whatever is at that cell address.  As such if you want to do SUMPRODUCT(Matrix1, Matrix2), you can do the following assuming my example Matrix would be Matrix one:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(1:1048576,ROW($J$9)-($B$1-1)/2,COLUMN($J$9)-($B$1-1)/2):INDEX(1:1048576,ROW($J$9)+($B$1-1)/2,COLUMN($J$9)+($B$1-1)/2),Matrix2)
```

Note the ":" and how it is being used to separate the two INDEX formulas from above.  Its the same as saying G6:M12 when you set the value of B1 to 7.

If I understood everything correctly and all your matrices have a constant centre point you could use the above method and you would either need to supply the n value in B1 or Calculate the n to suit your needs.

Caveat:  In order for your matrix to have a centre, n or the value in B2 will need to be an odd integer.

Comment: @fzd take a look at the INDEX option that was added.

Comment: INDEX alsmost does the trick. I am using quite a lot of volatile functions, but I dont' understand how to use it and have a square centered on position J9, which width would be n (not always "2" or "3", but a variable number).

Comment: With the way INDEX is being used, dont target the center of your matrix, target the upper left corner.  Build you matrix out from the upper left corner.  This means you centre point will always be shifting down and right.  It means you would need to adjust your formulas for developing the matrix.  Use a formula to determine where the center position is, and then set your matrix formula to calculate based on its position from the centre point.  Admittedly its not as nice in the current format as the offset.

Comment: Is J9 the centre of all your matrices up to the maximum size?

Answer (score 0):

After some discussion with ForwardEd, it appears the function I was looking for is `OFFSET`, and, in my example, 
`SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(ConvolutionKernel!$B$2; -1, -1, 3, 3); OFFSET(Data!J8; -1, -1, 3, 3))`.